# Acessar url com ajax e pegar retorno

Tags: php, javascript

Tenho o seguinte link para acessar:

`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&maxResults=5&q=brksedu&key={YOUR_API_KEY}`

Quando acessado diretamente ele retorna um array assim:

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#searchListResponse",
 "etag": "\"I_8xdZu766_FSaexEaDXTIfEWc0/Y3YIz5M5plLC7zcRxibBlX47-aU\"",
 "nextPageToken": "CAIQAA",
 "regionCode": "BR",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 159704,
  "resultsPerPage": 2
 },
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
   "etag": "\"I_8xdZu766_FSaexEaDXTIfEWc0/UDOCuqtHTALjQUfIUcgkxYCRNPg\"",
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#channel",
    "channelId": "UCWKtHaeXVzUscYGcm0hEunw"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2010-07-30T02:06:06.000Z",
    "channelId": "UCWKtHaeXVzUscYGcm0hEunw",
    "title": "BRKsEDU",
    "description": "Canal de gameplays e vlogs de games e entretenimento! Ou seja: tenho o melhor trabalho do mundo! =) Jogos favoritos: Life Is Strange, Shadow of the ...",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/-4VkVjXuRhlU/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/MtEHi_HPB5E/s88-c-k-no-mo-rj-c0xffffff/photo.jpg"
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/-4VkVjXuRhlU/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/MtEHi_HPB5E/s240-c-k-no-mo-rj-c0xffffff/photo.jpg"
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/-4VkVjXuRhlU/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/MtEHi_HPB5E/s240-c-k-no-mo-rj-c0xffffff/photo.jpg"
     }
    },
    "channelTitle": "BRKsEDU",
    "liveBroadcastContent": "upcoming"
   }
  },
  {
   "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
   "etag": "\"I_8xdZu766_FSaexEaDXTIfEWc0/iFm3mPRQQ_2agP1yM-gTXXMIzlk\"",
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "uIMfeKEyOCE"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2016-09-25T14:48:40.000Z",
    "channelId": "UCWKtHaeXVzUscYGcm0hEunw",
    "title": "FORZA HORIZON 3 #5 - Correndo Contra um Trem!? (PC Gameplay)",
    "description": "Vídeo gameplay do jogo Forza Horizon 3, game exclusivo Microsoft disponível para Xbox One e PC. Forza Horizon 3 está disponível dublado e legendado em ...",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/uIMfeKEyOCE/default.jpg",
      "width": 120,
      "height": 90
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/uIMfeKEyOCE/mqdefault.jpg",
      "width": 320,
      "height": 180
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/uIMfeKEyOCE/hqdefault.jpg",
      "width": 480,
      "height": 360
     }
    },
    "channelTitle": "BRKsEDU",
    "liveBroadcastContent": "none"
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

Minha pergunta é: Como acessar essa url com ajax e pegar os elementos do retorno. Por exemplo, quero pegar o channelTitle.
Obrigado!!!

Comment: procura json no google q vc acha

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/

Answer (score 2):

**Código:**

```
success : function(data) {

    var jsonData = JSON.parse(data);

    var items_length = jsonData.items.length;
    var items = jsonData.items;

    for (var i=0; i < items_length; i++){
        console.log(items[i].snippet.channelTitle);
    }
}
```

**Resposta:**

Se a requisição foi bem sucedida será retornado o status da requisição HTTP igual a `200 OK` para o `AJAX` e o método `success` será chamado com os dados em formato `JSON` (o mesmo que você colocou acima).

Iremos converter o `JSON` que foi recebido para atributos JavaScript com a instrução `JSON.parse(data)` para que a gente possa acessar o objeto e seus atributos.

E no final iremos tratar e iterar o objeto e seus atributos recuperando e colocando no `console` do navegador o valor do atributo `channelTitle` dos itens que vieram a partir da requisição.

**Exemplo e execução:**

Você pode com seu navegador favorito abrir o exemplo que criei no JSFiddle [clicando aqui](https://jsfiddle.net/giancarlodebian/2Lfgma5b/), abrir o `console` do seu navegador e executar o exemplo sendo possível ver o atributo `channelTitle` dos itens sendo printados no `console` de seu navegador. No meu caso não precisei converter uma String com um JSON dentro para um objeto JavaScript utilizando a instrução `JSON.parse` porque já atribui um objeto JavaScript na variável `conteudo`.